# Stability of Polynomial Planar Systems (differential equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the general system of differential equations $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$ and $\dot{y}=g(x,y)$ where $f$ and $y$ are polynomial functions and $f(0,0)=g(0,0)=0$. What are the conditions on $f$ and $g$ such that the Lyapunov function $V(x,y)= \alpha x^2+ \beta y^2$ where $\alpha, \beta \ge 0$ can certify the stability of the the origin?
Thank you, in advance, for your response!

Comment: How far did you get? Could you answer the question if $f$ and $g$ are linear?

Comment: For a linear system, e.g., $f=ax+by$, $g=cx+dy$, we can apply the Lyapunov function and the conditions on the stability of the system is $a\le0$, $d\le0$, $\alpha \beta ad-0.25(\alpha b + \beta c)^2 \ge 0$.
However, If $f$ and $g$ are quadratic functions, I do not know how to certify the negative definiteness of $\dot{V}$.
Let's say $f=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ and $g=ex^2+fxy+hy^2$.

Comment: In general, how can we certify the positive definiteness of a polynomial function of order $n$, i.e., $\sum_i a_i x^{b_i} y^{c_i}$